# How do I change the theme on an Android application?

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android application and I want to change the color and theme of the application. How can I do this?

Comment: +1 as it's a good question but a google search would've given you an answer in less time than it took to write the question

Comment: Related: [how to change theme at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482848/how-to-change-current-theme-at-runtime-in-android)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Dev guide explains how to apply themes and styles.](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

This:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#00FF00"
    android:typeface="monospace"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

Becomes this:

```
<TextView
    style="@style/CodeFont"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

By defining an xml theme file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

You can also apply styles to all activities of an application:

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

Or just one activity:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
          setTheme(); // Put the resId as the parameter
          super.onCreate(icicle);
     }
}
```