# Android app with changable skin/theme

Tags: android, themes, skin

I am planing to build an android media player that has changeable skin. What i aim at is like the user can download skins and use it with his android media player. Is it possible to pack skins as a different package and use them. Please help really important

Answer (score 0):

You can't change skins at runtime, but you can swap themes.

[How to change current Theme at runtime in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482848/how-to-change-current-theme-at-runtime-in-android)

You can't download new themes from looking at the API.  Application.setTheme( resourceID ) doesn't take any other types of arguments.  So unfortunately I don't think this is possible without some API changes.

Comment: Is it possible to change the theme of home screen launcher?

Comment: Yes it is.  However, I don't see from the API how to change the theme for a single application from anything other than a resource ID.