# Apps with different themes

Tags: android, themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change current Theme at runtime in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482848/how-to-change-current-theme-at-runtime-in-android)

I want to set in the PreferenceScreen a theme for my whole app. Is there any way to do it global for all activities (not explicit in onCreate with setTheme)?

Update: I know the manifest entry theme, but how can I chance it dynamic at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is explained in another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482848/how-to-change-current-theme-at-runtime-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can set the app theme by setting it in the manifest file.
You want to add the following to your application element.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
```

Switch the mentioned theme for the one you want to use.

Here's a link to the Android docs for the application element: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html

Comment: I know the manifest entry for the theme, but how can I chance it dynamic (at runtime)?

Comment: See the answer below for a link to a previous post that explains how to change it at runtime.