# Change action bar color in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using the app theme `Theme.Black` in my app. In this theme the action bar is gray. How I can change color of my action bar? This is my attempt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="mytheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black" >

    </style>
    <style name="Widget.MyApp.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>



</resources>
```

However, it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 25):

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("COLOR"));
```

it worked for me   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8024797)

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me. getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.material_blue_gray1)));

Comment: Per my experience, setting this has a drawback, i.e. the action bar menu color will not change.

Comment: It works perfect just edit the comment like @Ataru wrote.

Answer (score 10):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#C1000E</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#E5ED0E</item>
</style>
```

I have Solved Using That.

Comment: I have soved using this.

Answer (score 7):

```
 ActionBar actionBar;

 actionBar = getActionBar(); 
 ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#93E9FA"));     
 actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
```

Comment: `new ColorDrawable( 0x93E9FA );`

Answer (score 3):

Just simply go to res/values/styles.xml file and edit the xml file to change the color of xml file .Here is the sample code

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
```

//      below code is for changing the color of action bar

```
    <item name="colorPrimary">"type your color code here. eg:#ffffff"</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Hope it will help you...

Answer (score 2):

Updated code:

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color)));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Android default action bar then. If you change from java then some time show previous color.

[image]

**Example**

Then your action bar code inside "app_bar_main". So go inside app_bar_main.xml and just add Background.

**Example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#33691e"   <!--use your color -->
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<include layout="@layout/content_main1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you also. It's from the website:

http://nathanael.hevenet.com/android-dev-changing-the-title-bar-background/

> First things first you need to have a custom theme declared for your application (or activity, depending on your needs). Something like…

```
<!-- Somewhere in AndroidManifest.xml -->
<application ... android:theme="@style/ThemeSelector">
```

> Then, declare your custom theme for two cases, API versions with and without the Holo Themes. For the old themes we’ll customize the windowTitleBackgroundStyle attribute, and for the newer ones the ActionBarStyle.

```
<!-- res/values/styles.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="ThemeSelector" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/WindowTitleBackground</item>
    </style>

    <style name="WindowTitleBackground">     
        <item name="android:background">@color/title_background</item>
    </style>

</resources>

<!-- res/values-v11/styles.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="ThemeSelector" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">     
        <item name="android:background">@color/title_background</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

> That’s it!

Comment: What about `values-v14` folder?

Comment: What do you mean, what's about?

Comment: I am sorry. I meant, how do I change using Java instead of XML?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly you need to change App theme during runtime otherwise it does not make sense to use java instead of XML definitions.

For that you can have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482848/how-to-change-current-theme-at-runtime-in-android

Answer (score 0):

if you have in your layout `activity_main`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

you have to put

in your Activity this code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

onclick buttons `c2` to fetch and change the color of action bar and notification bar according to button's background, hope this helps

```
int color = c2.getBackground()).getColor();
int colorlighter = -color * 40 / 100 + color;
getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(colorlighter);
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(colorlighter);
ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(color));
```

`colorlighter` is used to set color of notification bar a little lighter than action bar

`color` is the background color of button `c2`, according to which we change our color.