# How to change programmatically background color of action bar items

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

It is easy to set a default color of the items background in action bar by setting:

```
<item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/action_bar_item_background</item>
```

in application theme.

I would like to change this color only for one of my fragments. How to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 11):

Have you tried the solution from user3225831
mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21297231/1738838

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("COLOR"));
```

Comment: Yes I did, it is changing the background color of the action bar but NOT background color of menu items.

Comment: You mean the background color of the tabs?

Comment: I am talking about action bar items. Look at [2] on this picture http://developer.android.com/images/ui/actionbar@2x.png

Comment: Icons are should be in png (background transparent)

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think a solution could be to define your own style for this case and then just switch the styles.

Comment: @RajeshM: I think Tomasz doesn't want to change the color of the hole action bar, but only of the background of the small square where the icon of his action bar item is placed in.

Answer (score 7):

Use simple one line code... Pass RGB values of the required color

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(248, 248, 248)));
```

For Color codes, you can use this website:
http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm

Comment: @RuchirBaronia I guess we'll never know

Answer (score 1):

I have found a simple workaround of this problem. You can set transparent color to the background of action bar item. Then changing color of the action bar will change background of the item. I don't see possibility to change item color without recreating an the activity.

Comment: @ramesh6233 if you can recreate activity it is not a problem, otherwise use my tip.

Comment: Can you tell me how to set transparent color to action bar item. Thank you.

Comment: Define your custom theme in `styles.xml` file using code from my question and then use it in AndroidManifest file:
        `<application
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
        ...`