# Android Studio, can I set a background color in Java class instead of its XML file?

Tags: android, android-background

In my MainActivity.java is where I coded for my preference settings screen to work.

Here's my activity_main.xml design:

[image]

In the activity_main.xml design and text, you can see background colors for AppBarLayout and TabLayout are purple.

Here's my activity_main.xml text:

[image]

Yet the MainActivity bar is still blue. How do I turn it purple if in activity_main.xml it doesn't work anywhere. Do I have to add color in MainActivity.java class? How do I go about doing that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41097686/dynamically-change-values-of-colors-xml-to-change-look-and-feel-of-android-app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change programmatically background color of action bar items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25081706/how-to-change-programmatically-background-color-of-action-bar-items)

Comment: You can check this answer for your detailed [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41380885/8387050) Thanks

Comment: Pavneet_Singh, my question is not a duplicate of the link you sent. The link you sent, solves PART of the problem but not the full problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my MainActivity bar is done programmatically, none of the above answers worked.

The only thing that worked for me is in my MainActivity.java class to programmatically add the following line:

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to **values** folder and open **color.xml**

put your desired color in **colorPrimary** and **colorPrimaryDark**
**For example :**

```
<color name="colorPrimary">[Your Color]</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">[Your Dark Color]</color>
```

That's it!!