# Changing action bar color

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I used this website to create files to change my action bar color:

http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=beerPortfolio&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&neutralPressed=1&backColor=f80%2C100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6%2C100&tabColor=f80%2C100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2%2C100&accentColor=f80%2C100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF%2C100&cabHighlightColor=f80%2C100

Once I downloaded the .zip, I extracted the files and added them to my app. Now that they are in the app, how can i make them take effect? Just placing them in the app does not change the colors of my action bar.

Comment: You should be able to view the code portion of the design and you should see something like #000000, set of rgb values, or a literal name for a color somewhere in the code which you can change. Use the search bar and look for occurrences "color".

Comment: In addition, I noticed that the download file contains png files. In this case, you may not be able to change the colors because the colors in the png files are pretty much final unless you edit them in something like paint or maybe use an API to change the colors in a program.

Comment: The one sin the download are the correct colors I want, thast the point of the website I used.

Comment: There should be a way to set my downloaded theme in my manifest.

Comment: @Mike Add android:theme="@style/Theme.Example" in your Manifest file. Here Theme.Example is the style name in styles.xml that is generated in zip folder.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the solution from user3225831 mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21297231/1738838

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("COLOR"));
```

**UPDATE**

```
mActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xff00DDED));
mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
just insert the @style/Theme.Beerportfolio in manifestfile instead of application theme.
```