# Change background color of android action bar at runtime

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I'm trying to change the background color of android action bar at runtime, according to an image VibrantColor.

I found some references, but neither worked for me.

> [Change action bar color in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930587/change-action-bar-color-in-android)
>
> [How do I change the background color of the ActionBar of an ActionBarActivity using XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us)

I have this code to get the color from the image, and it works.

```
public int getImageColor(Bitmap foto) {
    Palette palette = Palette.generate(foto);

    List<Palette.Swatch> swatchList = palette.getSwatches();

    int maiorPopulação = 0;

    int color = 0;

    for (Palette.Swatch sw : swatchList){
        if (sw.getPopulation() > maiorPopulação) {
            maiorPopulação = sw.getPopulation();
            color = sw.getRgb();
        }
    }

    return palette.getVibrantColor(color);
}
```

Then I try to set the returned color to the ActionBar:

```
public static void alteraCor(Fragment fragmento, int color) {
    ActionBarActivity atividade = (ActionBarActivity)fragmento.getActivity();

    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = atividade.getSupportActionBar();

    if ( fragmento instanceof Detalhes )
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(
                Color.red(color),
                Color.green(color),
                Color.blue(color)
            )));
        else
            actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(fragmento.getResources().getColor(R.color.fundoEscuro)));
    }
```

I called `alteraCor` from `onCreate` and from `onAttach` on Fragment, but neither of them worked.

**EDIT:**

I use the folowing Style:

```
    <style name="VendasFacil" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/Fonte</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/fundoPrimeiroPlano</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/fundoPrimeiroPlano</item>
        <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/VendasFacil.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTheme" tools:ignore="NewApi">@style/VendasFacil.ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="VendasFacil.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/fundoEscuro</item>
        <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
        <item name="displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
        <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
        <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_drawer</item>
    </style>
```

I do not have the color I want to use as background previously to put it in a style file. It is as if the color was defined by the user at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a style for that. You can then change the style at runtime to have the actionbar reflect it.

This might be useful: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#AdvancedStyles

Here is an example of a style changing the actionbar color:

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">ANY_HEX_COLOR_CODE</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I do not have the color I want to use previously to put it in a style file. It is as if the color was defined by the user at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=1&hairline=1&neutralPressed=0&backColor=3ddf74%2C100&secondaryColor=3ddf74%2C100&tabColor=fff%2C100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2%2C100&accentColor=56f9d5%2C100&cabBackColor=fff%2C100&cabHighlightColor=f80%2C100) . It's generate XML files. Copy to your project. It's easy and nice.

Comment: I do not have the color I want to use as background previously to put it in a style file. It is as if the color was defined by the user at runtime.

Comment: The Action Bar Style Generator is deprecated with the new AppCompat

Answer (score 0):

Hey there appears to be a small bug in your code:

```
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(
        Color.red(color),
        Color.green(color),
        Color.blue(color)
    )));
```

Your are setting the r the g and the b value to the hex value of the color. What you need to do instead is simply:

```
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(color));
```