# Android Studio / Trying to change background color in app?

Tags: android, xml, android-webview, background-color

[Hey guys I'm having a small issue I cant for the life of me figure out what I did wrong to not allow myself to change the background color in my app.  See image for example at the Top where it says AppStack I want to change the background color of that instead of it being white.  Is there something I am missing any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vy8I8.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean to the AppBar color. 
You can do it with

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getRes‌​ources().getColor(R.c‌​olor.mycolor));
```

Add value in colors:

```
<color name="mycolor">#FFFFFF</color>
```

The answer is from here:
[Change action bar color in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930587/change-action-bar-color-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do in XML
Try this [tutorial from google](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)

If you want to set it up in code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompact {

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
         actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE)); // set your desired color
         ...
      }
     ...
  }
```

Comment: Apologies, in your onCreate() method for the activity, after your setContentView(your xml). Place this, forcing the view drawing to take this into effect.

Comment: I'm not sure I have this set up correctly im not seeing that

Comment: Updated the answer, let me know if it helps.