# Is it possible to change theme in each intent in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-actionbar, themes

I'm coding an Android app that fetches Sun image from NASA site. I wanted to change ActionBar color in each intent. For example to have AIA094 wavelength intent's ActionBar color green and AIA211 intent's ActionBar color as pink. Is it possible in Android Studio?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930587/change-action-bar-color-in-android. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom style in AndroidManifest.xml in each activity

for example

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
<activity android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```