# Android changing style when application's running

Tags: android, onclick, styles

I want to use two styles in my application : android:Theme.Black and android:Theme.Light. In my app user can choose style when application is installed and run.

My question : **How to change style of app, when it's running ?** It's very important for me. Very,very thanks,

PS
Style is defined in res/values/styles.xml

Comment: Use search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482848/how-to-change-current-theme-at-runtime-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it :

`getApplication().setTheme(R.style.BlackTheme);`

/res/values/styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="BlackTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black">
    </style>    
</resources>
```