# how to change text color for whole app programatically in android

Tags: android, rgb

I want to set text color for whole app,what i am doing is that,I have created color picker,When user select color from color picker,That selected color should set for whole app,I don't know how to do this..i am new in android

```
 This is my rgb code..
 String rgbString = "R: " + Color.red(color) + " B: " + Color.blue(color) + " G: " + Color.green(color);
```

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14276550/1777090)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a color attribute and store it in SharedPreferences and associate your full app to that color. When user select color from color picker, just change the SharedPreferences  property of that color .

**Why use SharedPreferences**

Because you can't modify resources at runtime. Now full app text color will be changed.

```
textview.setTextColor(Color.argb(0,200,0,0)) //r,g,b and fourth parameter is optional
```

Store three int variable r,g,b in `sharedPreferences` and set them as above. No need of fourth parameter

Comment: how to set this color to whole app

Comment: You need to set the color for all `TextView` as shown in the answer...there is no shortcut that only one line will change to whole app text color..

Comment: If the color is fixed, you can create `Custom Textview` and use it in the app..But as you said, the user will select the color from color picker and that color will be set to the textView..then you need to code for all textview manually.

Comment: i think you have to create a custom theme for it

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom TextView ,that is checking the setting.
here [is a tutorial for it](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_custom_components.htm)

Comment: but i want to set text color of whole application

Comment: The custom textview will update when colour settings is change. Every time the custom textview is create it will check the witch colour the text should be. You should not forget the reload or update the currentview when the colour has been changed

Comment: sore for late response i had created textview,button and edit text,I want to change color of all this component..

Comment: Maybe you should creates theme´s for it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301554/android-change-app-theme-on-onclick is a example