# Android using switchpreference to set color background

Tags: android, colors, switch-statement, android-preferences, setbackground

How can I change the color of the app I'm trying to develop.

I have used a switch statement under preferences menu, but do not know how I can code this, so that when the user clicks on the switch, the background color is changed across the whole app.

Does anyone have any idea of how this can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the user to change the theme using preferences. This will change the background color throughout the application in accordance with the choice. The following thread is talking about the same problem: [How to change current Theme at runtime in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482848/how-to-change-current-theme-at-runtime-in-android). Hope this helps.