# How to make changable skin/theme on my Android app?

Tags: android, styles, themes, skin

I have an Android app. I want to have a changeable skin/theme in my Android app. 
For example, a dark theme to a light theme.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482848/how-to-change-current-theme-at-runtime-in-android

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html