# How to set the height of the action bar programmatically

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I'm implementing a custom view inside the Android action bar. The problem is that under some conditions I need to double the height of the action bar to allow the view to be displayed completely. I can set the height using a custom theme, but this height is static.

Is is possible to change the action bar height programmatically?

Comment: It seems that it's not possible and that also goes against the Android Style Guide. Alternatives are: Create a custom view or ask the designer to use a standard android pattern.

Comment: check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.LayoutParams.html. I also have same problem, In AppCompact Custom Actionbar  in 2.X actionbar is fullscreen. This might help you.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using reflection (possibly not a good idea):

```
    Window window = getWindow();
    View v = window.getDecorView();
    int actionBarId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar", "id", "android");
    ViewGroup actionBarView = (ViewGroup) v.findViewById(actionBarId);
    try {
        Field f = actionBarView.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("mContentHeight");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(actionBarView, 50);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {

    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {

    }
```

Comment: There's no need anymore to do this since with lolillop you can use the new toolbar api and set the height http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491689/how-do-i-declare-an-extended-height-toolbar-action-bar-on-android-lollipop

Comment: Could not work: DeclaredField "mContentHeight" seems no longer available

Answer (score 2):

RyanCheu's answer worked for me, but I found that if I selected text in an activity, the text selection toolbar appeared at the default action bar size, which resized the activity, which removed the text selection, so it was impossible to use the Copy and Select All functions. I ended up going back to using themes to set the action bar height, and changing themes programmatically using setTheme() and recreate(). Example code is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37974527/462162