# Setting Android theme background color using SharedPreferences

Tags: android, colors, background, themes, setting

I have a theme defined in .xml file and applied to the application tag in Manifest file. I also have a hex value of color stored in SharedPreferences. Is there any way to set this color as a theme's background?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the background color of your window or Activity and the color
value can come from your SharedPreferences value using setBackgroundColor.

If it is the Activity window that you want the background color changed,
you can do the following:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light));
```

Just replace the android.R.color.holo_red_light with the value from your XML file.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot alter the theme as it is already "compiled", but you can switch between them. For that you can check [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482848/how-to-change-current-theme-at-runtime-in-android)

Comment: The problem is that i get the color value dynamically from user so it can't be defined before.

Comment: if you are doing so, you may need to make your original theme transparent, since it is drawn prior to your onCreate call and you will see a change in colors from original theme to your color. No the most user friendly.