# How can I change background color of all xml pages through three radio buttons

Tags: android

How can I change background color of all xml pages through three radio buttons, one is Red, another is Blue, and other is Green. When I will click onto one of them, then the background color of all XML pages will be changed into that selected color. Pls help me.

Comment: post your code  here .......

Comment: Do you mean that you want to change the backgrounds through a preferences(Settings) screen radio buttons

Comment: you want to change whole theme of app or only the single screen where the three radio buttons are present?????

Comment: do it with custom theme set it dynamically by setTheme method.

Comment: post some sample code what are you trying to do

Comment: I have just created an xml page which contain three radio buttons, namely RED, BLUE, GREEN.

Comment: Do you mean to change all your layouts background to change on the radio button click or something ? or you want to change just the current layout where the radio button is ? In either case, on click of any of the radio buttons, save the preference of the color you want to change and on the onResume call for any of the layouts(With Activities), change the color of the background that you have saved in the preference.

Answer (score 2):

You should `findViewById()` your root `layout` and set within the method `setBackgroundColor()`. And by switching `RadioButton` you specify different color. See example below.

```
RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.layout.the_id);
RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.yourFirstRadioButton);
rb.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

and then:

```
OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener (){
   public void onClick(View v) {
      switch(v.getId()){
      case 0: //assume 0 is red
           rLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(Color.RED));
           break;
      case 1: //assume 1 is blue
           rLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(Color.BLUE));
           break;
       case 2: //assume 2 is green
           rLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(Color.GREEN));
           break;
      }
   }
}
```

If you want to change layout color in ALL `Activities` you should remember the value and pass it through `Intent` or declare `static` variable with the current color.See examples:

In `Activity` with `RadioButton`s:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class); 
intent.putExtra("color", green);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in `NextActivity` you get it like this:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if(bundle != null){
   switch(bundle.getInt("color")){
   case 0: // 0 was red
         rLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
         break;
   case 1: // 1 was blue
         rLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
         break;
   case 2: // 2 was green
         rLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
         break;
   }
}
```

With the `static` variable I hope you know how to deal, so by switching `RadioButton`'s you assign the value and in another `Activity` you check the value in `switch/case` statement as I described above.

Another common way is saving value in `SharedPreferences`. This is a good practice and it is light-weight, but also depends how many `Activities` you have. If just 2 - doesn't make sense, if 10 - yes. Nice answer is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values).

That's it. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

do it with custom theme set it dynamically by setTheme() method check below link

[set theme dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482848/how-to-change-current-theme-at-runtime-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

This is one option:

You can save in `SharedPreferences` the color you toggled. For example:

Create your `SharedPreferences` reference:

```
      SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(    getActivity().getPackageName(),Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Then when you select a color (for example blue) do:

```
     prefs.edit().putInt("TAG", Color.Blue).apply();
```

Then on any `Activity` `onCreate` method (after the `setContentView` call) or if its a fragment on `onViewCreatedMethod` you do:

If `Activity`:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout."layout_id");

    SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(getActivity().getPackageName(),Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    int backgroundColor = prefs.edit().getInt("TAG")
    View rootView = findViewById(R.id."layout_id");
    rootView.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);

}
```

if `Fragment`:

```
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(getActivity().getPackageName(),Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    int backgroundColor = prefs.edit().getInt("TAG")
    view.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
    }
```

This way, when you load a page the color of its background will be changed to the one you've store in preferences.