# Different Colored Statusbar in each fragment

Tags: android, colors, android-actionbar, fragment, statusbar

How can I define a different Statusbar and Actionbar color for each fragment ?

**At the moment.**

[image]

**How it should look.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2482848/1168654

Comment: Have a look at `Toolbar` it is much more flexible than old actionbar that is hardcoded in activity UI

Comment: You need only to change backgound of `ActionBar` ?   Have you tried to use `ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("COLOR")); `

Comment: @CROSP yes, but **getActionBar()** doesn't work in my fragment.

Comment: Of course it will not work in `Fragment` use something like this `getActivity().getActionBar()` I will post the answer explaining how implement this better ok ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would highly recommend you to migrate to new approach - [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html). It is much more flexible and you can customize it as plain `View`.

About your question.
You can just get `ActionBar` object and `setBackground` programatically.
Here is short example
`ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("COLOR IN HEX 0xFFFF6666 for instance"));`

I will show how would I implement this. This is more about architecture and patterns.

Use some base class for `Fragment` it would be better to have base class for `Activity` as well. Lets consider

`public class BaseFragment extends Fragment`

And you `Activity` class in which your fragment lives.

`public class MainActivity extends Activity`

And you have to define responsibilities of `Activity` in this case and create interfaces

In your case to work with `ActionBar`

Create interface

```
public interface ActionBarProvider {
  void setActionBarColor(ColorDrawable color);
}
```

Make your activity implement this interface

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ActionBarProvider {
    public void setActionBarColo(ColorDrawable color) {
      ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
      bar.setBackgroundDrawable(color));
    }
}
```

And finally in `BaseFragment` in `onAttach`

```
public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mActionBarProvider = (ActionBarProvider) context;
}
```

Make `mActionBarProvider` variable protected and make each fragment extend   `BaseFragment` and you can change action bar color from any fragment like this `mActionBarProvider.setActionBarColor(new ColorDrawable());`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx, i will test it tomorrow. @CROSP

Comment: sir what about the status bar???? This ans seems for action bar... I have the same problem...