# How to set theme to Main Activity from another activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-theme

I have two activities. One is main activity and another is settings activity.

I want to change theme from settings activity when user selects color from color picker dialog.

For now I am able to change the theme , but its only changing theme for settings activity not of main activity. How can I set theme to main activity?

Settings Activity:

```
public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


          Theme.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);



    final ColorPickerDialog colorPickerDialog = new ColorPickerDialog();
    colorPickerDialog.initialize(R.string.dialog_title, new int[]{Color.CYAN, Color.LTGRAY, Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.MAGENTA, Color.RED, Color.GRAY, Color.YELLOW}, Color.YELLOW, 3, 2);
    colorPickerDialog.setOnColorSelectedListener(new ColorPickerSwatch.OnColorSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onColorSelected(int color) {



            //  startActivityForResult(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            //         ThemedPreferenceActivity.class), SETTINGS_ACTION);

            if (color == Color.CYAN) {
                Theme.changeToTheme(Settings.this, Theme.THEME_DEFAULT);
                no = 0;
            }
            else if (color == Color.LTGRAY)

            {
                Theme.changeToTheme(Settings.this, Theme.THEME_WHITE);
                no = 1;
            }
            else if (color == Color.BLACK) {

                Theme.changeToTheme(Settings.this,Theme.THEME_BLUE);
                no = 3;

            }
            Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "selectedColor : " + color, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });



    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

    editor.putInt("color_1",no);
    editor.putInt("color_2",no);
    editor.putInt("color_3",no);
    editor.commit();

    LinearLayout theme = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.theme);

    theme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            colorPickerDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "colorpicker");
        }
    });


}
```

Theme :

```
 public class Theme {

    private static int sTheme;

    public final static int THEME_DEFAULT = 0;
    public final static int THEME_WHITE = 1;
    public final static int THEME_BLUE = 2;

    /** * Set the theme of the Activity, and restart it by creating a new Activity of the same type. */
    public static void changeToTheme(Activity activity, int theme) {
        sTheme = theme; activity.finish();

  activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, activity.getClass()));
    }

    /** Set the theme of the activity, according to the configuration. */
    public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity) {
        switch (sTheme) {
            default: case THEME_DEFAULT:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.BlueTheme);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit :

Main Activity :

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();


    no = pref.getInt("color_1", 0);        
    no = pref.getInt("color_2", 0);
    no = pref.getInt("color_3", 0);

    if(no == 0)
    {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    }

    else if(no == 1)
    {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Solarized);
    }

    else if(no == 2)
    {
        setTheme(R.style.BlueTheme);
    }


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Thank you..

Comment: see the question it may be helpful. [How to change current Theme at runtime in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482848/how-to-change-current-theme-at-runtime-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

```
     public void updateTheme(int themeID) {
        setTheme(themeID);
         Intent intent = getIntent();
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }
```

Comment: I want to change theme dynamically when user selects the color from color picker dialog.. This is already set in manifest.@ahmad aghazadeh

Comment: How and where to use this method?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change theme dynamically until unless you restart the current activity.

You can achieve this using two approaches for your questions:

1. Store onCreate of activity before setting content view check the shared the data from preference and set theme accordingly.
   From **Setting** activity set shared data.
   In **MainActivity** check shared data.

   ```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       if (checkColorData("navcolor").equals("SomeColor"))
       {
           setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
       }
       else
       {
           setTheme(R.style.AppThemeDarkNav);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use toolbar for action bar and use some color changeable views you can change color by calling **setBackgoundColor**

Comment: I tried this still there is no change on main activity. Please can you check edited question and tell me what's wrong?@Flygenring , @Bharath Kumar