# Android - How to switch theme with a transition at runtime

Tags: android, themes

I know that you need to restart the activity to apply a new theme, so maybe the way this is done is with a different approach.

This is what I will like to accomplish, as you can see the app it's not restarted and there's a transition between the ligth and dark theme.

[image: Example]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482848/how-to-change-current-theme-at-runtime-in-android?rq=1