# How to change actionModeCloseDrawable icon dynamically?

Tags: android, android-actionmode

I am setting up the actionModeCloseDrawable icon as below

```
<item name="actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/ic_actionbar_back</item>
```

But I want to change it pro-grammatically on paticular event.

Is there any way to do so?

I have tried defining two styles and changing it on runtime, but that also didn't work.

Comment: You have to create 2 themes and [switch between themes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482848/how-to-change-current-theme-at-runtime-in-android) upon particular event.

Comment: Theme can be set before `SetContentView()`. I am not switching activity. I want to achieve it in the opened Activity.

Comment: `actionModeCloseDrawable` is a theme attribute. As far as I am concerned, there is no way to change the attribute without restarting activity.

Comment: I am using it with `contextual Actionbar` and  MULTI_MODE selection of `ListView`. So on some particular event I want to change the drawable of `actionModeCloseDrawable`. Hence restarting Activity doesn't seem to be feasible.

Comment: I get your use-case, I'm just telling whether it is achievable or no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before
[image]

Code

```
 new Handler(Looper.myLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ((AppCompatImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.action_mode_close_button)).setImageDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_person_white_24dp));
        }
    },5000);
```

After
[image]

Assumption & State:

1. You are using support action mode.
2. In my example, `ActionBar` is a part of Fragment hence `getActivity().findViewById(int resId)`
3. I have used `Handler` to simulate the delay of an event you are talking about.

Hope this helps.