# Is there any way to create app theme manually without pre-defined attributes?

Tags: android

Assume that, If we **not pre-defined a theme**, some style, some color in XML resources files. Do we able to create our theme at runtime programmatically and use that theme afterward?

**I mean:**

1. If we just defined a default app theme, **Can we change the value of theme attrs** to be a value that not defined in resource xml files programmatically? (like set the colorPrimary to be #7e57c2 in some class but **effect whole app**) or change the reference of it to another color source like local storage or some external files.
2. If we store values(colorPrimary: "#7e57c2") in local storage or sharedPref and we use a custom view instead of the default. **Can we get that color and use it in our custom view class?**

I wondering that If I didn't define several themes in resource files but just **one default theme** and then I fetched the theme's values from the backend. What is the **proper way to do to use that value** instead of some defined value?

P.S. I'm not intending to switch between pre-defined style at runtime. I want to know how to create a new style or edit the default value and use it afterward at runtime.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change current Theme at runtime in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482848/how-to-change-current-theme-at-runtime-in-android)

Comment: @AnasMehar I don't think so. In that topic is about switching between pre-defined style at runtime but I want to know how to change the value of style not just switch to another style.