# Using custom attributes in layout crashes app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I'm building an Android app and I'm trying to apply a custom theming, and I want to use some custom attributes.

I've defined the attrs in the `attrs.xml` as such:

```
<resources>
    <attr name="baseColor" format="reference" />
    <attr name="accentColor" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

and in my `styles.xml` I've added the following values to my theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue_color</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/blue_color</item>

        <item name="baseColor">@color/blue_color</item>
        <item name="accentColor">@color/red_color</item>
</style>
```

Finally, in my XML layout, I'm applying these attributes on a button as such:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/sign_up_button"
            android:background="?attr/accentColor"
            android:textColor="?attr/baseColor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="@string/sign_up_button" />
```

However, when I run my app, it crashes with a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f040046 a=-1}` which of course means that my custom attribute was not found. Am I missing anything? I've already defined the colors and the attrs in my theme, and I've applied the theme to my activity in my manifest. The full stack trace can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/uSwdQetW)

Comment: Post the full stack trace, not just one line.

Comment: @GabeSechan I've updated my question with the full stack trace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it turns out the activity that was crashing was using a different theme, which did not have the custom attributes. I've removed the custom theme form the manifest and the attributes work as expected since they are defined in my App's global theme.

Answer (score -1):

For your custom button you need to declare styleable in attrs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="UpdateButton">
    <attr name="setType" format="string" />
    <attr name="setContent" format="string"/>

  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Your styleable name being the Class name of your custom view.

[Creating a View Class](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view)

For building a custom theme to expand upon your comment you can swap around themes rather than using attrs.xml

[Change Current Theme At Runtime - Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482848/how-to-change-current-theme-at-runtime-in-android)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'm not using a custom button, just a normal AppComatButton, with a custom background and textColor. However, since I want to have different themes for my app, I'm defining the colors as theme attributes and applying them to my button. Can I do it, or do I need to crate a custom Button that extends the AppComactButton?

Comment: Off my head, I think you don't need the attrs.xml in that case then. Just have different groups of style themes other than "AppTheme" and swap that around. I've never tried to swap themes, though always wanted to, so I don't have code to confirm this is the correct method.

Comment: Added a link in my answer that might help