# How to implement theme appearance setting like YouTube in your android studio project

Tags: android, default, darkmode, lightmode

I am creating an app in android studio using java , I want to create a theme appearance setting like YouTube where user have 3 options to select one of them... 1) Use device theme 2) Dark theme 3) Light theme. But I don't know how to implement it in java activity and xml activity, can anyone help me ?

here I am attaching screenshot of what I want.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2FBj.jpg)

Comment: Please, provide the screenshot of needed design.

Comment: @Yegorf thanks for commenting . I attached screenshot to my question, hope you will understand now easily what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a comprehensive description of how you might achieve that using XML layouts and styles: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme

If you're completely new to XML theming in Android, then watch this video first: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Owkf8DhAOSo

Answer (score 0):

It is calls Dialog with radiobuttons. All about it + implementation example - https://suragch.medium.com/adding-a-list-to-an-android-alertdialog-e13c1df6cf00

Comment: thanks for answering . now i am able to implement it in xml , but i also want to know how i switch  dark theme, light theme, and device theme in java code . for example when i click on dark theme radiobutton my app should change into dark theme,when i select device theme option then app theme will be the same as device theme.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482848/how-to-change-current-theme-at-runtime-in-android